# Ghost CMS weird navigation issue

Tags: ghost

So I install Ghost CMS and it is working great, but I noticed recently that the navigation settings (where I add new links to the menu and such) are acting strange and not working right.

[image: weird menu glitch]

So in the image above you will notice the ':80' port being added onto the domain. Which is fine I guess, but what is odd is that if i click out the field and then back into it it adds another port ':80' and continues to do that as many times as I click out, also if I tried to delete and save it immediately adds them back in. Look at Teaching and you will see what it ends up looking like.

Also when I go to the site front page and click one of the menu items I see a 404 error in the console saying the page doesn't exists.

I can't figure out what is going on it was working just fine a few weeks ago and I have touched anything on the server. I am stumped, I don't really know enough about Ghost so I am relying on a better expert to help me out here. I am using the Bitnami Ghost Cloud Image. and have the theme bleak installed.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well on version 0.11.7 but interestingly, I'm not seeing it on another instance i have setup that happens to be version 0.11.5. Yet, you're post would have been from an earlier version. Did you ever sort this out? Find the root cause?

Comment: No never figured it out, I installed another instance of it on a separate setup and it didn't occur there, but as far as I can tell they are identical I think it might be a setting in the underlying system either with node or ubuntu

Comment: In my case, I have both instances on the same server and the same version of node. They are just running on different ports.... Regardless, thank you for replying.